# Temperature and Heat question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

So I have a problem about calculating the specific heat of a metal. I'm using the philosophy "Heat gained = Heat lost". The problem is:

> When 50g of a metal at 280C is put into a calorimeter containing 400g of water at 25C, the final temperature of the system is 30C. What is the specific heat of the metal in J/KgC? (Specific heat of water is 4186 JkgC.

`Known variables:
Mass(metal) = 0.050kg, Temp(metal) = 280C.
Mass(water) = 0.400kg, Temp(water) = 25C, C(water) = 4186 JkgC.
Temp(final) = 30C.`

`Heat Gained = Heat lost so.....
C(metal) * Mass(metal) * DeltaTemp(metal) = C(water) * Mass(water) * DeltaTemp(water)
So I solved for C(metal) to get -> 
C(metal) = (C(water) * Mass(water)* DeltaTemp(water))/(Mass(metal) * DeltaTemp(metal))
If I plug the numbers in, I get ->
C(metal) = (4186 * 0.4 * (30-25))/(0.05 * (30-280)) = 8372/(-12.5) = -669.76JkgC`

The answer seems wrong to me and I'm not sure what I did wrong. I followed the example in the book, so I'm assuming that the heat that was in the calorimeter of water is equal to the heat lost AFTER the 270C metal is put in it. And I solved for the unknown variable.

I looked at the table of Specific heats and none of them have such a low negative number (or any negative number at all).

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Feel free to change the tags, I wasn't sure which ones to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong except the extra minus sign. The idea that heat gained equals heat loss is spot on but both quantities need to be positive in this case. One way I like to think about this would be that the change in heat of the metal plus the change in heat of the water must add to zero. In this equation, "H_metal + H_water = 0", the sign of H_metal is negative as it is losing heat and H_water will be positive.